# Color the Image setting on QProgressBar

Tags: c++, css, image, qt, qprogressbar

Actually I set  an image on a `QProgressBar` and want to change the color of image according to selected part of `QProgressBar`.

I tried covering my image with `QProgressBar` color but that fills the image, but as my image is not a rectangle it color the whole `QProgressBar` and not just the image.

Is it possible to change color of image only using qt (with C++)

Comment: How did you set the image on a `QProgressBar`?

Comment: Actually i set an image Using QLabel.Put the QLabel over the QProgressBar.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Qt Style Sheet Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html). You can customize your own QProgressBar, and add your own `setProgress()` function which should update the [value property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#value-prop). You could modify the image background, the border, margins... depending of the value of the current value.

See QSS examples for more detail: [Example Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#qprogressbar)

Comment: Actually i m not looking for StyleSheet.I m looking for a method to set color on image according to selection on QProgressbar.It must be noted that image is set on the QProgressBar.

Comment: This is wrong, please fix it. There is no function named `setProgress` in [`QProgressBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#details). And if you meant [`setValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#value-prop) it is not a virtual function that you need to override, and even if you really had to, it does **not** have to do with styling at all. Please try reading the [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qprogressbar) you provided.